# Behaviour of ImageView when scaled

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view

I do some operations with my Views that scale then trough:

```
imageView.setScaleX(2);
imageView.setScaleY(2);
```

On that ImageView I put a image that is two times greater than it, as expected when the scale is 1, the Bitmap is scaled down to the view size, my question is:
When the view is scaled up, the portion of the bitmap I see is the original image or the scaled-down image scaled up.

The difference is that if a tiny image is scaled up we lost contrast on letters, if it's the original image it wont.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. When you scale the image up you get poor quality? You want to know how to make a small image look better when scaled up?

Comment: Scaling up the image get poor quality (even if the size of the view is the same as the original image). I want to know the behaviour of drawing of ImageView when the View is scaled.

Answer (score 0):

When you scale an image up you're loosing quality. In you're case, you're doubling the width and height therefore, for each pixel you get 4 pixels assigned to it. The extra 3 pixels won't give you the quality you wanted.

If you want to go back to the original size you should decode the source again. This way you'll get the quality you're looking for.